# split() in python3 not returning value as expected(spliting the whole string character wise rather than space wise)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
size = int(input())
#a = [0 for x in range(size)]
a = input()
b=[]
a.split()
print (a[0])
for x in a:
    if is_number(x):
        b.append(int(x))
print (b)
```

> Input : 4
>
> 12 8 4 0
>
> Output: 1
>
> [1, 2, 8, 4, 0]
>
> expecting :  12
>
> [12 , 8, 4, 0]

What am I doing wrong here?
NB: `a.split(" ")` also not working

Comment: `str.split` returns a new list... you want `a = a.split()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split does not alter the string inplace, it returns. so, just do the following

```
a = a.split()
```